# How records are getting commited in oracle while using OracleCommand in .Net?

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net

I am using `Oracle` as the DataBase for a `.Net` application. If I run a DML operation using `Sql Plus` or `Oracle SQlDeveloper`, I need to explicitly **commit** the changes for persistance. But when I execute the same query as an inline query using `OrcleConnection` and `OracleCommand` objects in `.Net` I do not need to specify the `commit`. How does the commit happen here.

P.S. I am not using `transaction` here.

Comment: As background, note that some of the key technical features of Oracle have always been that readers do not block writers, writers do not block readers, and row locks do not escalate to page or table locks. Because of this developers on Oracle do not have a technical need to commit frequently as developers on other systems have had to, so they commit on completion of functional transactions (like "generate an invoice") rather than after every change to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's the difference. SQLDeveloper and SQL+ *do* use transactions. As you don't, you automatically have a transaction per command that gets commited if it doesn't fail.

Comment: You mean to say that If I execute the following query using OracleCOmmand in .Net, it updates all records if it is successful and rollsback all the updates if it encounters error while updating a single record. Update SampleTable set SampleColumn='New SampleColumn';

Comment: Yes, you always have a transaction. If you don't start one yourself, it will be generated for you at the lowest possible level. A statement can either succeed or fail, there is no way for it to update only half your records, fail in the middle and leave the updated half updated. A statement will either be complete or all changes it did will be rolled back. Please note that this goes for using transactions as well. A single statement is atomic. It either works complete or not at all, no matter what kind of transaction.

Comment: If there is an implicit transacation, Why do I need to use transaction when I use Oracle as DataStore?

Comment: Because the implicit transaction is for one statement only. If you need multiple statements to either succeed together or fail together, you need to create your own transaction. Example: a financial transaction of 20$. You need to subtract 20$ from the senders account and add 20$ to the receivers account. You want them to either both succeed or both fail, not anything in between. So you start a transaction before, execute both statements and then commit or rollback the transaction. That way there's always 20$ in the system, never nothing (subtract worked only) or 40$ (add worked only).